# How do I count the characters, words, and lines in a file, using Perl?

Tags: perl, file, counting

What is a good/best way to count the number of characters, words, and lines of a text file using Perl (without using wc)?

Comment: presumably without doing a system call to use the 'wc' command?

Comment: This is not a homework assignment although I admit it could look like one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's the perl code.  Counting words can be somewhat subjective, but I just say it's any string of characters that isn't whitespace.

```
open(FILE, "<file.txt") or die "Could not open file: $!";

my ($lines, $words, $chars) = (0,0,0);

while (<FILE>) {
    $lines++;
    $chars += length($_);
    $words += scalar(split(/\s+/, $_));
}

print("lines=$lines words=$words chars=$chars\n");
```

Comment: Nicely concise but not obfuscated.

Comment: for word count, you want:  scalar(split);
That will split on /\s+/ and drop leading empty fields, just like awk does.

Comment: As a note sort of related to glenn's, you can say "length;" instead of "length $_;" and Perl will default to using $_. However, using the defaults on split() is more beneficial, as it even has a default regex.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: here, are you happy now: perl -ne 'END{print"$. $c $w\n"}$c+=length;$w+=split'

Comment: @Brad Gilbert why not go all the way: open my $fh, "<", "file.txt" or die "could not open file: $!";

Comment: @Chas: Reasons not to do so are many, but they include not specifying the encoding. See my answer.

Comment: `use warnings` says "Use of implicit split to @_ is deprecated"

Answer (score 7):

A variation on bmdhacks' answer that will probably produce better results is to use \s+ (or even better \W+) as the delimiter. Consider the string "The  quick  brown fox" (additional spaces if it's not obvious). Using a delimiter of a single whitespace character will give a word count of six not four. So, try:

```
open(FILE, "<file.txt") or die "Could not open file: $!";

my ($lines, $words, $chars) = (0,0,0);

while (<FILE>) {
    $lines++;
    $chars += length($_);
    $words += scalar(split(/\W+/, $_));
}

print("lines=$lines words=$words chars=$chars\n");
```

Using \W+ as the delimiter will stop punctuation (amongst other things) from counting as words.

Comment: Using \W will split "nit-picking" into two words. I don't know if this is correct behavior or not, but I always thought of hyphenated words as one word rather than two.

Comment: It's one of those 'you pays your money, you makes your choice' things. Personally, I usually roll my own regex that fits the definition of 'word' I need at the time. Quite often split can be less than helpful because it is a negative match. A normal regex matches the characters you *do* want, generally a better idea. You could certainly do the same sort of thing using m/.../g and calling it in list context.

Comment: This only counts code points, not characters (=graphemes).  And it forgets to set the encoding.

Comment: @tchrist - yup, I was aware of that but didn't think it worth adding. You're probably right. One the other, good point - I wasn't thinking there. I'm going to leave it as is as it's so long ago it doesn't seem worth changing given other answers

Answer (score 4):

The [Word Count tool](http://en.literateprograms.org/Word_count_(Perl)) counts characters, words and lines in text files

Answer (score 3):

Here.  Try this Unicode-savvy version of the wc program.

- It skips non-file arguments (pipes, directories, sockets, etc).
- It assumes UTF-8 text.
- It counts any Unicode whitespace as a word separator.
- It also accepts alternate encodings if there is a `.ENCODING` at the end of the filename, like `foo.cp1252`, `foo.latin1`, `foo.utf16`, etc.
- It also work with files that have been compressed in a variety of formats.
- It gives counts of **Paragraphs, Lines, Words, Graphemes, Characters**, and **Bytes.**
- It understands all Unicode linebreak sequences.
- It warns about corrupted textfiles with linebreak errors.

Here’s an example of running it:

```
   Paras    Lines    Words   Graphs    Chars    Bytes File
       2     2270    82249   504169   504333   528663 /tmp/ap
       1     2404    11163    63164    63164    66336 /tmp/b3
    uwc: missing linebreak at end of corrupted textfiile /tmp/bad
      1*       2*        4       19       19       19 /tmp/bad
       1       14       52      273      273      293 /tmp/es
      57      383     1369    11997    11997    12001 /tmp/funny
       1   657068  3175429 31205970 31209138 32633834 /tmp/lw
       1        1        4       27       27       27 /tmp/nf.cp1252
       1        1        4       27       27       34 /tmp/nf.euc-jp
       1        1        4       27       27       27 /tmp/nf.latin1
       1        1        4       27       27       27 /tmp/nf.macroman
       1        1        4       27       27       54 /tmp/nf.ucs2
       1        1        4       27       27       56 /tmp/nf.utf16
       1        1        4       27       27       54 /tmp/nf.utf16be
       1        1        4       27       27       54 /tmp/nf.utf16le
       1        1        4       27       27      112 /tmp/nf.utf32
       1        1        4       27       27      108 /tmp/nf.utf32be
       1        1        4       27       27      108 /tmp/nf.utf32le
       1        1        4       27       27       39 /tmp/nf.utf7
       1        1        4       27       27       31 /tmp/nf.utf8
       1    26906   101528   635841   636026   661202 /tmp/o2
     131      346     1370     9590     9590     4486 /tmp/perl5122delta.pod.gz
     291      814     3941    25318    25318     9878 /tmp/perl51310delta.pod.bz2
       1     2551     5345   132655   132655   133178 /tmp/tailsort-pl.utf8
       1       89      334     1784     1784     2094 /tmp/til
       1        4       18       88       88      106 /tmp/w
     276     1736     5773    53782    53782    53804 /tmp/www
```

Here ya go:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
#########################################################################
# uniwc - improved version of wc that works correctly with Unicode
#
# Tom Christiansen <tchrist@perl.com>
# Mon Feb 28 15:59:01 MST 2011
#########################################################################

use 5.10.0;

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => "all";
use sigtrap qw[ die untrapped normal-signals ];

use Carp;

$SIG{__WARN__}  = sub {
    confess("FATALIZED WARNING: @_")  unless $^S;
};

$SIG{__DIE__}  = sub {
    confess("UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION: @_")  unless $^S;
};

$| = 1;

my $Errors = 0;
my $Headers = 0;

sub yuck($) {
    my $errmsg = $_[0];
    $errmsg =~ s/(?<=[^\n])\z/\n/;
    print STDERR "$0: $errmsg";
}

process_input(\&countem);

sub countem { 
    my ($_, $file) = @_;

    my (
        @paras, @lines, @words,
        $paracount, $linecount, $wordcount, 
        $grafcount, $charcount, $bytecount,
    );

    if ($charcount = length($_)) {
        $wordcount = eval { @words = split m{ \p{Space}+  }x }; 
        yuck "error splitting words: $@" if $@;

        $linecount = eval { @lines = split m{ \R     }x }; 
        yuck "error splitting lines: $@" if $@;

        $grafcount = 0;
        $grafcount++ while /\X/g;
        #$grafcount = eval { @lines = split m{ \R     }x }; 
        yuck "error splitting lines: $@" if $@;

        $paracount = eval { @paras = split m{ \R{2,} }x }; 
        yuck "error splitting paras: $@" if $@;

        if ($linecount && !/\R\z/) {
            yuck("missing linebreak at end of corrupted textfiile $file");
            $linecount .= "*";
            $paracount .= "*";
        } 
    }

    $bytecount = tell;
    if (-e $file) {
        $bytecount = -s $file;
        if ($bytecount != -s $file) {
            yuck "filesize of $file differs from bytecount\n";
            $Errors++;
        }
    } 
    my $mask = "%8s " x 6 . "%s\n";
    printf  $mask => qw{ Paras Lines Words Graphs Chars Bytes File } unless $Headers++;

    printf $mask => map( { show_undef($_) } 
                                $paracount, $linecount, 
                                $wordcount, $grafcount, 
                                $charcount, $bytecount,
                       ), $file;
} 

sub show_undef {
    my $value = shift;
    return defined($value)
             ? $value
             : "undef";
} 

END { 
    close(STDOUT) || die "$0: can't close STDOUT: $!";
    exit($Errors != 0);
}

sub process_input {

    my $function = shift();

    my $enc;

    if (@ARGV == 0 && -t) {
        warn "$0: reading from stdin, type ^D to end or ^C to kill.\n";
    }

    unshift(@ARGV, "-") if @ARGV == 0;

FILE:

    for my $file (@ARGV) {
        # don't let magic open make an output handle

        next if -e $file && ! -f _;

        my $quasi_filename = fix_extension($file);

        $file = "standard input" if $file eq q(-);
        $quasi_filename =~ s/^(?=\s*[>|])/< /;

        no strict "refs";
        my $fh = $file;   # is *so* a lexical filehandle! ☺
        unless (open($fh, $quasi_filename)) {
            yuck("couldn't open $quasi_filename: $!");
            next FILE;
        }
        set_encoding($fh, $file) || next FILE;

        my $whole_file = eval {
            use warnings "FATAL" => "all";
            local $/;
            scalar <$fh>;
        };

        if ($@) {
            $@ =~ s/ at \K.*? line \d+.*/$file line $./;
            yuck($@);
            next FILE;
        }

        $function->($whole_file, $file);

        unless (close $fh) {
            yuck("couldn't close $quasi_filename at line $.: $!");
            next FILE;
        }

    } # foreach file

}

sub set_encoding(*$) {
    my ($handle, $path) = @_;

    my $enc_name = "utf8";

    if ($path && $path =~ m{ \. ([^\s.]+) \z }x) {
        my $ext = $1;
        die unless defined $ext;
        require Encode;
        if (my $enc_obj = Encode::find_encoding($ext)) {
            my $name = $enc_obj->name || $ext;
            $enc_name = "encoding($name)";
        }
    }

    return 1 if eval {
        use warnings FATAL => "all";
        no strict "refs";
        binmode($handle, ":$enc_name");
        1;
    };

    for ($@) {
        s/ at .* line \d+\.//;
        s/$/ for $path/;
    }

    yuck("set_encoding: $@");

    return undef;
}

sub fix_extension {
    my $path = shift();
    my %Compress = (
        Z       =>  "zcat",
        z       => "gzcat",            # for uncompressing
        gz      => "gzcat",
        bz      => "bzcat",
        bz2     => "bzcat",
        bzip    => "bzcat",
        bzip2   => "bzcat",
        lzma    => "lzcat",
    );

    if ($path =~ m{ \. ( [^.\s] +) \z }x) {
        if (my $prog = $Compress{$1}) {
            return "$prog $path |";
        } 
    } 

    return $path;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

There is the [Perl Power Tools](http://www.metacpan.org/module/PerlPowerTools) project whose goal is to reconstruct all the Unix bin utilities, primarily for those on operating systems deprived of Unix.  Yes, they did [wc](https://metacpan.org/source/BDFOY/PerlPowerTools-1.002/bin/wc).  The implementation is overkill, but it is [POSIX compliant](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/wc.html).

It gets a little ridiculous when you look at the GNU compliant implementation of [true](https://metacpan.org/source/BDFOY/PerlPowerTools-1.002/bin/true).

Comment: Most of the fancy 'true' implementation is POD. Still ridiculous.

Comment: Schwern: I’ve been reïmplementing quite a bit of PPT for Unicode smartsiness. I’ve lately done `cat -v/od -c`, `expand`, `fmt`, `grep`, `look`, `rev`, `sort`, and `wc`.  All are improved over the originals.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this while googling for a character count solution.
Admittedly, I know next to nothing about perl so some of this may be off base, but here are my tweaks of newt's solution.

First, there is a built-in line count variable anyway, so I just used that. This is probably a bit more efficient, I guess.
As it is, the character count includes newline characters, which is probably not what you want, so I chomped $_.
Perl also complained about the way the split() is done (implicit split, see: [Why does Perl complain "Use of implicit split to @_ is deprecated"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436160/why-does-perl-complain-use-of-implicit-split-to-is-deprecated) ) so I tweaked that.
My input files are UTF-8 so I opened them as such. That probably helps get the correct character count in the input file contains non-ASCII characters.

Here's the code:

```
open(FILE, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", "file.txt") or die "Could not open file: $!";

my ($lines, $words, $chars) = (0,0,0);
my @wordcounter;
while (<FILE>) {
    chomp($_);
    $chars += length($_);
    @wordcounter = split(/\W+/, $_);
    $words += @wordcounter;
}
$lines = $.;
close FILE;
print "\nlines=$lines, words=$words, chars=$chars\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-serious answer:

```
system("wc foo");
```

Comment: ITYM: my ($lines, $words, $chars) = split(' ', `wc foo`);

Answer (score 1):

Reading the file in fixed-size chunks may be more efficient than reading line-by-line.  The `wc` binary does this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use constant BLOCK_SIZE => 16384;

for my $file (@ARGV) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or do {
        warn "couldn't open $file: $!\n";
        continue;
    };

    my ($chars, $words, $lines) = (0, 0, 0);

    my ($new_word, $new_line);
    while ((my $size = sysread $fh, local $_, BLOCK_SIZE) > 0) {
        $chars += $size;
        $words += /\s+/g;
        $words-- if $new_word && /\A\s/;
        $lines += () = /\n/g;

        $new_word = /\s\Z/;
        $new_line = /\n\Z/;
    }
    $lines-- if $new_line;

    print "\t$lines\t$words\t$chars\t$file\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this gives you any benefit. Under the hood, as it were, perl's <> operator is using buffered IO. All you have done here is rewrite something built-in with something that has to be interpreted.

Comment: True.  At least with my installation of 5.8.8, Perl buffers 4096 bytes at a time, and there's no performance benefit to doing this manually -- as you suspected, if anything, it's actually worse.  I like reminding people to think low-level though :)

Comment: And what do you do about UTF-8 chars that are split across block boundaries, eh?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to count CHARS and not bytes, consider this:
(Try it with Chinese or Cyrillic letters and file saved in utf8)

```
use utf8;

my $file='file.txt';
my $LAYER = ':encoding(UTF-8)';
open( my $fh, '<', $file )
  || die( "$file couldn't be opened: $!" );
binmode( $fh, $LAYER );
read $fh, my $txt, -s $file;
close $fh;

print length $txt,$/;
use bytes;
print length $txt,$/;
```

Comment: Perl defaults to using the system locale.  If your system is modern, the system locale will be an UTF-8 encoding, and thus Perl IO will be UTF-8 by default.  If not, you probably should be using the system locale and not forcing UTF-8 mode...

Comment: Wrong, ephemient. Perl defaults to the system locale, but prints characters 128-255 as "?" for backwards compatibility. To print proper UTF-8, one should say binmode($fh, ":utf8"); before using the filehandle. In this case, "use utf8;" is useless - it tells Perl that the source code can be in UTF-8, which is unnecessary unless you have variables names like $áccent or $ümlats.

Comment: @Chris Both my Perl 5.8 and 5.10 are documented as having `-C SDL` as the default, and `perl -e 'print "\xe2\x81\x89\n"'` produces "⁉" as expected -- not "???" as you seem to expect.

Comment: I think those three hex values are combining into one UTF-8 character. And UTF-8 characters will print in Perl. Just not the ones from 128-255. Trying any one of those three hex codes individually on my machine gives me "?", whereas prefixing it with binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8"); gives me "â" for \xe2 and non printing characters for the other two. And as far as I can tell, I have no default setting of "-C" anything.

Comment: `echo $'\xe2\x80\x99' | perl -ne'print length,$/'` outputs 4 while `echo $'\xe2\x80\x99' | perl -CSDL -ne'print length,$/'` outputs 2, so I must be misremembering and Chris is correct.

Comment: @Berov: You’ve got the right idea!!  But see my solution for a rather more elaborate version.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to Perl beginners.
I tried to simulate MS word counting functionalities and added one more feature which is not shown using wc in Linux.

- number of lines
- number of words
- number of characters with space
- number of characters without space (wc will not give this in its output but Microsoft words shows it.)

Here is the url: [Counting words,characters and lines in a file](http://www.aliencoders.com/content/counting-wordscharacters-and-lines-file)