# Does the Perl default variable $_ or @_ behave differently on OS X to linux using split?

Tags: perl, cross-platform

I am new to Perl, and have searched long and hard for the answer to this problem, but I am stuck.

Take the following example:

```
my $filein = $ARGV[0];
open(SNPIN,$filein);

while(<SNPIN>)
{
   chomp;
   split(/\s+/);
   print "$_[0]\n";
}

close(SNPIN);
```

The test file that I am using has the following lines:

```
This is a test.
Is a test.
A test.
```

This script executes fine on our linux servers (with perl 5.10), outputting the first word of each line - although it gives me the following warning:

```
Use of implicit split to @_ is deprecated at scan_test.pl line 7.
```

but when I try to execute it on my local machine running OS X (with perl 5.12.3) I get the following error:

```
Useless use of split in void context at scan_test.pl line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $_[0] in concatenation (.) or string at 
scan_test.pl line 8, <SNPIN> line 1.
```

Obviously this is a dummy script. I have inherited someone else's extremely long and complicated script which is working on our servers but I would like to develop it locally without having to go through the entire script and reassign all default variable calls to another variable. No matter what I have tried (including "use v5.10;"), nothing will allow me to use the default variable on my local machine.

Any ideas? Help is most appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436160/why-does-perl-complain-use-of-implicit-split-to-is-deprecated

Answer (score 7):

It's not the platform, but the Perl version.

The warning you got on Perl 5.10 should've been a clue: [deprecated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) means "you should not use this, because it's going to stop working in some later version".  Obviously, it did stop working somewhere between Perl 5.10 and 5.12.

---

To fix it, just explicitly assign the list returned by `split` into an array.  If you want to keep using `@_`, this should work:

```
chomp;
@_ = split(/\s+/);
print "$_[0]\n";
```

but I'd really recommend using your own named array, since `@_` has a special meaning (it's used for passing parameters to subroutines):

```
chomp;
my @items = split(/\s+/);
print "$items[0]\n";
```

Comment: Correc.t Also note that `use v5.10` does not mean 'return to 5.10 compatibility mode', but rather 'require version 5.10 or higher'.

Comment: But just out of curious interest, his main question actually seems `I would like to develop it locally without having to go through the entire script and reassign all default variable calls to another variable`. Is there a way to acknowledge this was on purpose and suppress the warning (only for this error)?

Comment: Install the same version of Perl locally?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I have installed version 5.10 locally and it is behaving as expected. @Konerak you are right, I don't have the time to go through and change all the calls to the default variable in this script (which is several 000's of lines) - not to mention the many errors I would probably introduce by attempting to do so. It does seem to me that many scripts will break if updates are made to perl, why is this functionality deprecated?

Comment: @rmlc: It was deprecated because it was something unusual and surprising (nothing else in Perl puts its return value in `@_` when used in void/scalar context) and it made it too easy to accidentally overwrite your subroutine arguments if you used `split` inside a subroutine. As for fixing your script, it should be enough to look at all the lines that generate that deprecation warning in Perl 5.10 (you _are_ logging the warnings, right?) and replace `split` with `@_ = split`.

Comment: Note that this is detected at compile time, so `perl -c my_script` will print all the lines where it occurs.  It probably wouldn't take long to write a script to read the output from `perl -c` and do `s/split/\@_ = split/` on each line that generated the error.