# Perl Inline Array Sort (How to avoid 'implicit split' error)

Tags: perl, unix, sorting

I have the following array:

```
  my @anim = ('rn4,mm8,bosTau2,canFam2,dasNov1,echTel1',
  'rn4,mm8,oryCun1,bosTau2,canFam2,dasNov1,echTel1');
```

It contain multiple strings, each string are comma separated. 
What I want to do is to sort them based on the greatest members of the string.
Hence what I tried to do is this:

```
my @animsort = sort{scalar(split(",",$b)) <=> scalar(split(",",$a))} @anim;
```

But it gives this error:

```
Use of implicit split to @_ is deprecated at ./scripts/mycode.pl line 35
```

What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: I just saw code like this somewhere. Do the various strings in your array `rn4, mm8 ...` mean anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If "greatest member" means the last one, use a list slice:

```
my @sorted_anim = sort {
    (split /,/, $b)[-1] cmp (split /,/, $a)[-1]
} @anim;
```

Using a Schwartzian Transform:

```
my @sorted_anim = map $_->[0],
    sort { $b->[1] cmp $a->[1] }
    map [ $_, (split /,/, $_)[-1] ],
    @anim;
```

Or a Guttman-Rosler Transform:

```
my @sorted_anim = map /,(.*)/s,
    sort { $b cmp $a }
    map { (split /,/, $_)[-1] . ",$_" }
    @anim;
```

The Schwartzian Transform aims at improving efficiency by calculating the sort key only once for each element; Guttman-Rosler goes one better by also temporarily combining the sort key with the full data (often with pack, where the sort key is of known length; here just with a known delimiter character) in such a way that perl will use an optimized built-in sort routine instead of executing perl code for each comparison.

Comment: if my guess of your intent was right, it is a little odd that your sample data has both elements with the same last member.

Comment: +1 for Guttman-Rosler Transform, which I haven't seen before.

Comment: @ysth by greatest member I think @neversaint means the string with the most comma separated elements. So changing your 1st schwarzian transform map into `map [ $_, scalar(split /,/, $_) ]` does the business

Comment: but gets right back to the original question of not invoking the old deprecated scalar-context split functionality.  it should be `map [ $_, scalar( () = split /,/, $_ ) ]` then

Answer (score 2):

`scalar()` does not return the "greatest member of a string" or cause `split` to do so. Maybe you're looking for [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aUtil)'s `maxstr`?

```
use List::Util qw( maxstr );

my @sorted_anim = sort {
   maxstr(split /,/, $b) cmp maxstr(split /,/, $a)
} @anim;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort by the count of elements in each string, your code will do that.  I am not getting any errors with your posted code in Perl 5.16. Do you have an older version of Perl?  (I found [some evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436160/why-does-perl-complain-use-of-implicit-split-to-is-deprecated) that your code may generate the error in older versions).

Here is another option:

```
my @animsort = sort{(() = $b =~ /,/g) <=> (() = $a =~ /,/g)} @anim;
```

This sorts by counting the commas, rather than actually splitting the string.  The funny `() =` syntax is to make sure the regex is treated as being in list context, so we can count the matches.

Comment: or count commas with `$a =~ y/,//`

Answer (score 0):

Regexp could sole everything or you could remove the warnings with 'no warnings;' pragma locally.

```
my $comma_re = qr!,!;   
my @animsort = sort{$b =~ s!$comma_re!!g <=> $a =~ s!$comma_re!!g} @anim;
print Dumper(\@anim,\@animsort);
```

Comment: Problem: this actually modifies the data by deleting all the commas.  It is better to use `(() = $b =~ /$comma_re/g)`, even if it is rather ugly.